# Matrix multiplication function

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management, matrix

I am trying to multiply a vector (1 line, 4 columns) with a matrix (4x4); the vector represents some coordinates of a point, and, in my application, it is intended to have a lot of them (points). I wrote a function to do the multiplication :

```
    public static double[] Multiply(double[] point, double[,] matrix)
    {
        double[] aux = new double[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            aux[i] = 0; 
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            {
                aux[i] += point[j] * matrix[j, i];
            }
        }
        return aux;
    }
```

I think this should work properly.

The problem is this: the function is static, but every time I plan to use it, a new double[4] will be born(aux[]). Since I need this several hundred/thousand times (a second) I need to know if those doubles (aux), are stored in memory until I close the application, and therefore, crank up to big memory allocation. Isn't Garbage collector removing them (the old ones) ?

The other way is to build a proper class (matrix class) with a field double[] (this aux) and use that over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem.  The method is static, but there is no static *state* here.  If you had a `double[]` variable that was static then you'd need to be concerned.

As it is, the method will simply return the array to it's caller.  That caller could be storing that array in an instance field, inside of a collection, as a local variable, or who knows what.  Whenever that array is no longer referenced by any code that could ever be executed the garbage collection will clean it up.

So if whoever is calling this method is holding onto the result for a long time it will stay around for a long time.  If the caller doesn't hold onto it for very long it won't stay around for very long.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't worry about memory, GC will collect all of unused array. You can read more about Garbage Collection in MSDN:

- [Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx)
- [Garbage Collector Basics and Performance Hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx)
- [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx)
- [Garbage Collection and Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851764.aspx)